# Problem in using leaflet-geotiff in React

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

I am trying to use [leaflet-geotiff](https://github.com/stuartmatthews/leaflet-geotiff) in my react application. I followed all steps as in the documentation but encountered error in `L.leafletGeotiff()` saying:

```
Line 21:  'url' is not defined      no-undef
Line 22:  'options' is not defined  no-undef
```

The code is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import L from 'leaflet-geotiff/leaflet.js';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import 'geotiff/dist/geotiff.browserify';
import 'leaflet-geotiff/leaflet-geotiff-plotty.js';
import 'leaflet-geotiff/leaflet-geotiff-vector-arrows.js';
import 'geotiff/dist/main.js';
import 'plotty/dist/plotty.min.js';

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    var map1 = L.map("map").setView([27.664198, 85.361624], 30);
    var BaseOsm = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      }).addTo(map1);
    var windSpeed = L.leafletGeotiff(
      url = 'tif/wind_speed.tif',
      options = {
        band: 0,
        displayMin: 0,
        displayMax: 30,
        name: 'Wind speed',
        colorScale: 'rainbow',
        clampLow: false,
        clampHigh: true,
        //vector:true,
        arrowSize: 20,
      }
    ).addTo(map1);

  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ width: 600, height: 600 }} id="map">

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I have also included all links shown in documentation in public/index.html

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/geotiff@0.4.1/dist/geotiff.browserify.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/plotty@0.2.0/src/plotty.js"></script>
<script src="leaflet-geotiff.js"></script>
<!-- Load any renderer you need -->
<script src="leaflet-geotiff-plotty.js"></script>
<script src="leaflet-geotiff-vector.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've mis-interpreted the calling sequence for `leafletGeotiff`. It should be

```
  var windSpeed = L.leafletGeotiff(
         'tif/wind_speed.tif',
         {
            band: 0,
            displayMin: 0,
            displayMax: 30,
            name: 'Wind speed',
            colorScale: 'rainbow',
            clampLow: false,
            clampHigh: true,
            //vector:true,
            arrowSize: 20,
          }
```